# How do I know, that my Javascript executes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a portfolio and tried to code the site offline.
I want to make a image to fade out when it scroll with jQuery.

However, I think my JScript is okey (I'm new to it but it looks fine).
I think the problem is, that I linked to the jQuery wrongly.

Is there a way to find out, which one of the following things is the problem:

- My Jscript is just wrong
- I linked jQuery wrongly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.img-src_clean').css({
        'opacity': ((height - scrollTop) / height)
    });
});
```

```css
.blurred-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 450px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.img-src_clean {
 
 width:100%;
 height: 450px;
 background-image: url('http://imgur.com/w0wLfaF.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;


}

.img-src_blur {
 
 width:100%;
 height: 450px;
 background-image: url('http://imgur.com/MRD3m2q.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 opacity: 0;

}
```

```html
<!-- That's the head -->


<!-- Place for JS Scripts -->

<script src="Javascript.js"></script>   <!-- Are these two script links right? -->
<script src="jQuery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Here ends the head-->
<!-- Here begins the <body> -->


<div class="blurred-container">
<div class="img-src_clean"></div> <!-- That's where my JScript should attack-->
<div class="img-src_blur"></div>
</div>

<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
</div>
```

I hope it's not too messy.

P.S.: That's how my directory looks like

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: `<!-- Are these two script links right? -->` should be one line down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you're loading your own script (`Javascript.js`) **before** loading jQuery (`jQuery.min.js`), which will cause an error because your code expects jQuery to already be loaded. Reverse the order of those script tags, and for [best practices](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), move them both to the bottom of the HTML, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag.

> Is there a way to find out, which one of the following things is the problem:

Yes. Your browser has "dev tools" available that you can use to determine that. In most browsers, it's Ctrl+Shift+I (Cmd+Shift+I on a Mac) and/or F12.

One of those tools is the web console, which shows you lots of things, including scripting errors (e.g., when there's a syntax error in your code).

Another is the network tab, which shows you the network requests, including failed ones (e.g., when you've linked to the script file incorrectly).

Another one is a *debugger*, which you can use to view your code, set "breakpoints" (which cause the browser to stop at that line of code so you can inspect variables, etc.), step through the code statement-by-statement, etc.

Some resources:

- [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) - A site dedicated to the development tools built into Chrome.
- [Microsoft Edge Dev Tools](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/) - A site devoted to the "F12 Developer Tools" in the Microsoft Edge browser. (Most of it relates to IE11 as well.)

Comment: Thank you so much.. I knew the console but the error reports didn't make sense to me.. The switching of the scripts helped.